# How to use C# .net 4 to get webserver header time

Tags: c#, .net, http

In C# on .net 4.0 I'm trying to get the header date/time of a Internet web site.

My goal is to validate a local systems time (within seconds) of Internet time by using HTTP rather then SNTP.  I'm a SNTP fan but it won't do in this scenario. I found [this concept of using HTTP headers for time called "HTP"](http://www.vervest.org/foswiki/bin/view/HTP/WebHome) and want to replicate it in C#.

Tried to use [HttpWebRequest.Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers.aspx) collection using MSDN example on the page, which doesn't return me the Date (or much else).

If HttpWebRequest.Headers is a good way to go about getting this value, why can't I see Date in this result?  Is there a better way?

```
var myHttpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");
myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("\nThe HttpHeaders are \n\n\tName\t\tValue\n{0}",     
    myHttpWebRequest.Headers);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be reading the request headers, instead of reading the response headers:

```
var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");
var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("\nThe HttpHeaders are \n\n\tName\t\tValue\n{0}", response.Headers);
```